# Laravel 5.1 Cashier Webhook, handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-cashier

I'm on Laravel 5.1, stripe api 2015-10-16

I'm trying to handle: customer.subscription.deleted so I'm overriding **handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted**
but the method is never called.. (even if I return a 200 response without other lines of code the stripe log a 500 error response)

I'm routing as described in docs:

```
Route::post('/stripe/webhook', 'WebhookController@handleWebhook');
```

a custom controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Abbonamento;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Laravel\Cashier\WebhookController as BaseController;

class WebhookController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Handle a stripe webhook.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded($payload)
    {    
        $subscription = $payload['data']['object']['subscription'];
        $abbo = Abbonamento::bySubscription($subscription)->first();
        if ($abbo)
        {
            $abbo->makeStripePayment($payload);
        }
    }

    public function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted($payload)
    {    
        $subscription = $payload['data']['object']['id'];
        $abbo = Abbonamento::bySubscription($subscription)->first();
        if ($abbo and $abbo->subscribed())
        {
            $abbo->subscription()->cancel();
        }

        return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
    }
}
```

Someone can tel me why "handleInvoicePaymentSucceeded" works  but "handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted" was never called?

The question is not about my custom entity "Abbonamento", is just about why I see always error 500 as return response in the test env on stripe for customer.subscription.deleted,  and an ok response on 
invoice.payment_succeeded

Answer (score 2):

the problem was the method declaration,
looking at the laravel.log  I swiched it to:

```
public function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted(array $payload)
```

so the missed part was "array"

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention. `5.4` has `protected function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted(array $payload)`